# How can I change the "Return" button of a textField keyboard to the blue "Done" button in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have this textField:

```
TextField("Username", text: $username).textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
```

How can I change its keyboard return button to the Done button?